# matrix multiplication using parallel threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am writing a code for matrix multiplication using multi-threading.

The code works fine without multiple-threads. The code works when i add the line `t.join()`,but doing this won't parallelise the code.

All the threads will wait for their predecessor to finish.I want to execute them in parallel.

Run-time Error :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating
Abort trap: 6
```

When i looked up the error in SO mirrors,almost all of them where facing segmentation faults which gave this errror.

**Note : I am using a mac machine with gcc(clang).**

Here's my code:

```
void multiply (int a[][N],int b[][N],int n,int m,int p,int result[][N])
{
    int i,j,k;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<p;j++)
        {
            thread t(multiplyParallely,a,b,m,i,j,result);

            // t.join(); // Works When i add this line.But that doesnt parallelise.
            //multiplyParallely(a,b,m,i,j,result); // Obviously This Works
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Should be either detach, either store in vector and then join all.

Comment: using the method `join()` will result in threads waiting for others to complete. I don't want that.I want them to execute in parallel.

Comment: You have to join all of them together (i.e. after they *all* started) at the end of this function, otherwise `multiply` will return before the threads finished their work and potentially deallocate the input and output data when they are still working on it.

Comment: join() is a blocking statement. when the first child thread is launched for i=0, and j=0 (call this 0_0 thread), join is encountered. therefore the main thread will wait until 0_0 is finished. so this runs serial with t.join() uncommented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct reason why your app crash is that thread() object must be either detached or joined, otherwise, it's destructor throws an exception. This is happening when you exit your most inner loop.

Since I generally do not recommend detaching threads, the best soltution for you would be to have a vector of thread objects, and move your threads into this vector upon creation. In the end, just join all the threads in the vector.